# Excel 100 VBA sets Condtional Formatting but results incorrect

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2000, vba

I need to change a large amount of conditional formatting so I am writing a VBA subroutine. The following code sets the conditional format but the results are incorrect.
By that I mean I go to the sheet and I see the conditional formatting is correct. The results are incorrect. So the formula .8*($L$9/10) = 7.92 and should result in numbers >= 8 not colored red but all are colored red.

```
Sub SetFirst2(ByVal TheRow As Byte, target As Range)
  ' if it is less than .8*total/10
 target.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
  Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="="".8*($L$" & TheRow & "/10)"""
  target.FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 'Red
End Sub
```

And this is the way I call it:

```
Call SetFirst2(9, ShTheSheet.Range("B9:K9"))
```

Column L contains this formula:

```
=SUM(B9:K9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many double quotes in your formula definition. This should work (tested successfully with Excel 2010):

```
Formula1:="=.8*($L$" & TheRow & "/10)"
```